# Calculate the surface integral of the cylinder that cuts the cone

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

[image]

How do I calculate this? How do I find dS? What are the boundaries of the integral? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this at all?  What have you come up with?

Comment: I don't know where to start. My notes and textbook lack any examples of this type. @saulspatz

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

Note that the equation of the cylinder is

$$x^2+y^2=2x \implies x^2-2x+1+y^2=1\implies (x-1)^2+y^2=1$$

thus it is generate by a circle with radius $1$ and center at $(1,0)$.

For a fixed $z$, the intersection between the culynder ant the cone is given by

$$x^2+y^2=2x=z^2\implies x=\frac{z^2}2 \quad y=\sqrt{z^2-\frac{z^4}4}$$

The integrand function becomes

$$x^4-y^4+y^2z^2-z^2x^2+1=x^4-y^4+(y^2-x^2)(y^2+x^2)+1=1$$

[image]

Comment: Ok but how do I use this information to find dS?

Comment: @ChanceGordon Sorry but I can't work more than this at the moment.